# How to save a QR-Code in the gallery with any format?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I use zxing.mobile.forms nuget package.
The QR-Code is perfectly displayed on the screen display, but I also need to save this QR-Code in the gallery.
Can I convert it to image for further use? Can I save it right away, since it seems to be an image?
code in xaml:

```
<zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView IsVisible="False" x:Name="qrcode"
  BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" BarcodeValue="1">
   <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
       <zxingcommon:EncodingOptions Height="200" 
           Width="200">
       </zxingcommon:EncodingOptions>
   </zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
</zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
```

Comment: What if you just save recognized qr-code text for further use? You can save it in application settings for example.

Comment: you should generate it in code and then you can save it to the gallery and display it on the page

Comment: @Jason the qr code is generated by my button and displayed on the screen, that's why I can't imagine how to save it in the gallery, maybe there are some sources?

Comment: Looks like zxing creates a custom surface to display the qr-code. Not easy to get at. Maybe make it full screen, then programmatically take a screenshot?